# rich:dragSupport inside an ui:repeat

Tags: drag-and-drop, richfaces

I'm having issues with rich:dragSupport inside an ui:repeat. The component is displayed correctly but the drag action isn't called.

This code works:

```
<a4j:outputPanel style="width:100px;border:1px solid gray;padding:2px" layout="block">
    <rich:dragSupport dragIndicator=":indicator" dragType="type" dragValue="CALENDAR" reRender="editPanel">
        <rich:dndParam name="label" value="Calendar" />
    </rich:dragSupport>
    <h:outputText value="Calendar"></h:outputText>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

But this does not:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{formBuilderManagerBean.inputElements}" var="input">
    <a4j:outputPanel style="width:100px;border:1px solid gray;padding:2px" layout="block">
        <rich:dragSupport dragIndicator=":indicator" dragType="type" dragValue="#{input.componentId}" reRender="editPanel">
            <rich:dndParam name="label" value="#{msg[input.name]}" />
        </rich:dragSupport>
        <h:outputText value="#{msg[input.name]}"/>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
</ui:repeat>
```

The input object's getComponentId() method doesn't even get called!
HALP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently using `<c:forEach>` instead of `<ui:repeat>` works.